# PHP: Disparar una función cuando una propiedad de una clase es modificada

Tags: php, class

¿Qué tal?

Existe algún método para que, cuando se modifica un atributo de una clase, se lance automáticamente?

Por ejemplo, tengo la clase User:

```html
class User {

  private $name;
  private $modDate;

  public function setName($name){
    $this->name = $name;
  }  

}
```

Busco que cuando se realice un "setNombre('hola')" automáticamente se lance una función que me modifique la propiedad "$modDate".

Esto con Symfony lo resolvía bastante bien con los "onUpdate" del ORM de Doctrine, pero con "PHP" puro desconozco si existe algo similar.

Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta, estás en SO en español

Comment: @Aprendiz Ay! gracias! disculpa, no me di cuenta.

Comment: por qué no añades en tu función setName una llamada a otra función que modifique la fecha cuando se cumplan las condiciones que quieras? otra manera sería utilizar un intervalo que compruebe cada segundo por ejemplo que la variable $name no se haya modificado

Comment: @David, buenas y gracias por la respuesta! si, es lo que en un principio he hecho. Crear un método dentro de la clase e invocarlo dentro del setName() para que me actualice la fecha. Pero desconozco si existe algún método mágico que observe cuando las propiedades de un objeto varían para ejecutar una función.

Answer (score 1):

bueno si no haces uso de un evento, creo pudieras haer algo como

```
public function setName($name){
    if($this->name !== $name){
        $this->modDate = new DateTime('now');
    } 
}
```